# How to make sure that this part will appear as Chapter in this latex document?

Tags: chapters, input, chapter-page

I was given the PCtex `LaTeX` template by my university. Since I was more comfortable with Overleaf, I tried to run the file there and I found out that some problems occur when all the chapters are considered as Chapter 1.

The file is created separately for each chapter and uses `\input{}` to combine all the chapters. It means we actually refer to the new chapter every time we input each file. I don't know what the actual problem is.

The preamble:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{UTMThesis}
\usepackage{cite}
\makeatletter                       
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.} 
\makeatother

  \setlength{\voffset}{-2.11cm}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \lhead{}
  \chead{}
  \rhead{}
  \lfoot{}   
  \cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  %  
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{%
    {converted_graphics/}% inserted by PCTeX
    {/}% inserted by PCTeX
}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
 \input{Title.tex}
 \input{TableofContents(Final).tex}

 \mainmatter
  \input{Introduction.tex}    
  \input{LiteratureReview.tex} 
  \input{Chap3.tex}          
  \input{Chap4.tex}          
  \input{Chap5.tex}         
  \input{Chap6.tex}         
 \backmatter
\end{document}
```

In \usepackage{UTMThesis}, this is the code

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
 %\vspace*{20\p@}   %  \vspace*{15\p@}
 {\parindent \z@ 
     \centering  
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
     \if@mainmatter
     \normalsize 
          \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
      \par\nobreak
             \vskip 1.4\baselineskip 
     \fi
   \fi
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \normalsize     
        \bfseries #1\par\nobreak 
      \vskip 1.4\baselineskip %
 }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                  \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                \else
                  \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                  \@afterheading
                \fi}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
 %\vspace*{20\p@} % \vspace*{20\p@} %
 {\parindent \z@  
   \centering  
   \normalfont 
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \normalsize 
   \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 1.4\baselineskip  
 }}
 
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. How do you expect us to debug some code that we can't see? Please about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: There seems to be some problem in the preamble. Could you show them too? // By the way, always copy the code into a code block instead of screenshot.

Comment: I am so sorry & thank you so much for your comment @Miyase. I already edited my question and given some pictures.

Comment: Also note that there are compiling errors there. Maybe you should address them by looking into the error information :-) // And list of figures/tabls should be automatically generated with just one command.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry preamble means the code from the combinations of all files?

Comment: Preamble means the part above the `\begin{document}` where you set the document property.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I already copied the code and put it in the question.

Comment: The key part lies above `\begin{document}`. So you need to paste from the first line `\documentclass{xxx}` until `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I am so sorry. I already edited it. Thank you so much for the guidelines.

Comment: `UTMThesis` is a (private) class, not a style file, so you'd probably want to use `\documentclass{utmthesis}` instead of `\usepackage{UTMThesis}`. That said, there even is a ready-to-run template on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/universiti-teknologi-malaysia-thesis-template/vhhykxgsxcym

Comment: @Ingmar thank you so much for your help. The one provided in overleaf template was the old version.